# Letsencrypt generated files on windows - What is what?

Tags: ssl, apache2, lets-encrypt

I used [this blog](https://commaster.net/content/how-setup-lets-encrypt-apache-windows) to get a Letsencrypt certificate for an apache2 server on windows via letsencrypt-win-simple's manual mode. The tool reports success and all files were generated, however, I can't find any documentation on what is what. My apache2 has a temporary self-signed certificate installed with a self-generated private key. I assume the tool created an entirely new private key and certificate signing request and did not use the existing private key to verify my certificate? Sorry for my confusion, but I just found [explanations](https://serverfault.com/a/9717/430278) that show how confusing and flexible the formats can be used.

The tool generated the following (- my assumption what the file is):

- myurl.com-key.pem - Private key generated to encrypt the certificate signing request (csr) with?
- myurl.com-csr.pem - The unsigned csr file?
- myurl.com-gen-csr.json - Signed csr file in json to send to the CA?
- myurl.com-gen-key.json - Public key to send to the CA?
- myurl.com-crt.pem - My certificate?
- myurl.com-crt.der - This file is encrypted, but why and what's the difference to myurl.com-crt.pem?
- myurl.com-chain.pem - The chain of CAs used to create the certificate?
- myurl.com-all.pfx - An encrypted file containing everything? Do I need to generate the files for my apache2 from this via openssl or can I use the others?
- ca-CRYPTICODE-crt.pem - Another certificate? Or is this the final result? But what is myurl.com-crt.pem then?
- ca-CRYPTICODE-crt.der - Another certificate?
- Registration - Probably used for the registration process and not required anymore?
- Signer - Probably used for the registration process and not required anymore?

Which files do I need to configure my apache2 with? Which files are private and never shared with anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myurl.com-crt.pem` - this is the `SSLCertificateFile`
`myurl.com-key.pem` - this is the `SSLCertificateKeyFile`
`ca-CRYPTICODE-crt.pem` - this is the `SSLCertificateChainFile`
These 3 files you should specify in apache virtual host configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> myurl.com-key.pem - Private key generated to encrypt the certificate signing request (csr) with?

Private key to sign the CSR and use in association with the eventual certificate.

> myurl.com-csr.pem - The unsigned csr file?
>   myurl.com-gen-csr.json - Signed csr file in json to send to the CA?

Correct.

> myurl.com-gen-key.json - Public key to send to the CA?

Don't know what it is but the CA doesn't need your public key: it is already in the CSR.

> myurl.com-crt.pem - My certificate?

Correct.

> myurl.com-crt.der - This file is encrypted, but why and what's the difference to myurl.com-crt.pem?

No, this is another representation of the .pem file. It isn't encrypted.

> myurl.com-chain.pem - The chain of CAs used to create the certificate?

Correct.

> myurl.com-all.pfx - An encrypted file containing everything?

Correct.

> Do I need to generate the files for my apache2 from this via openssl or can I use the others?

You can use this as a PKCS#12 keystore with Java, *or* the others with Apache HTTPS.

> ca-CRYPTICODE-crt.pem - Another certificate? Or is this the final result?

Looks like another CA certificate. Have a look at it with some PEM utility.

> But what is myurl.com-crt.pem then?

Your signed certificate.

> ca-CRYPTICODE-crt.der - Another certificate?

DER form of ca-CRYPTICODE-crt.pem.

> Registration - Probably used for the registration process and not required anymore?
>   Signer - Probably used for the registration process and not required anymore?

Pass. Probably used in the Let's Encrypt registration or verification process.

Comment: Big thanks for the detailed answer. That really helped me out a lot! Important was also that the _ca-CRYPTICODE-crt.pem_ file should be used as the _SSLCertificateChainFile_ as mentioned by @Elvis Plesky.